# Regex get only the first occurance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this line :

```js
"Internal": "128 6GB RAM, 128 8GB RAM"
```

and I wanted to get only the first `6GB RAM` so I tried this :

```
^(\dGB RAM)
```

that doesn't match anything, if I removes the `^()` it matches all the `6GB RAM` & `8GB RAM`.

I tried it on https://regexr.com/ website

Comment: ```/(\dGB RAM)/``` remove the caret

Comment: that would match those two

Comment: This works: `'128 6GB RAM, 128 8GB RAM'.match(/\dGB RAM/)`

Comment: I wanted to get only the first occurance that is `6GB RAM`, this `(/\dGB RAM/)` match both GB RAM

Comment: ```/(\dGB RAM)/``` wil match first ```/(\dGB RAM)/g``` will much globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `/\dGB RAM/g` with the flag `g` (global) will match `6GB RAM` and `8GB RAM`
- but only `/\dGB RAM/` without the **g flag** will only match `6GB RAM`

You saw it matched both `6GB RAM` and `8GB RAM` because regexr.com adds global flag as default, turn it off and you'll only see it matches `6GB RAM`.

[image]

Comment: Nice! I didn't see that https://regexr.com/ website automatically use `/g`

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely hate regex, so you can do something like this:

```
first_ram = internal.split(",")[0]
```

Comment: welp that's illegal. because the JSON data actually random so sometimes it can't be split and would return an error.